# Arrows disappeared in smoothDivScroll

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm working on a page with rather big images using smoothDivScroll. I want to make a page with extra buttons and I made a html for this as you can see in http://www.festifood.nl/index-permanent-autoscrolling-kevin3a.html. But in this page the big arrows on the left and the right of the scrolling images, to scroll faster etc. have disappeared completely. And I don't know why and how. In the html I used earlier they are still there: http://www.festifood.nl/indexmetarrows.html.

Can anybody help to get the scrolling arrows back in the first html?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following JS error:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

This is due to recursion from your (X)limitReached functions on lines 136 - 158. As you already have 'backandforth' set as your default scrolling option in the default options, there is no need to reset the option and restart the scrolling each time.

Try removing / commenting out the all occurrences between lines 136 - 158 of:

```
$("div#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("option", "autoScrollingDirection", "backandforth");
startAutoScroll();
```

I hope this helps!